# Step-wise feature selection with caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection

can anyone direct me to a package/commands in R for performing step-wise feature selection, preferably using the `caret` package.

I have already used linear discriminant analysis (LDA), Random forest, PCA and a wrapper using a support vector machine. I was thinking of including a partial least sqaures or a gradient boosting method, but while trying to use them on multi-class data, they cause R to crash. People have reported similar experiences on multi-class data using `caret` when attempting to use `gbm`.

I realize that I haven't used a step-wise approach and I was searching for one that can be implemented on highly correlated, dependent variables for selecting the best performing 20 variables (for example) to create a parsimonious model.

Any suggestions would be welcomed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`caret` has a `stepLDA` method available in `train`:

```
slda <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris,
              method = "stepLDA",
              trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
```

This uses `stepclass` in the `klaR` package. There are also LDA feature selection tools in `caret` using `rfe` and `sbf` that would be helpful.

Max

Comment: Thanks Max, wondering if you have gotten around to solving the issue with `gbm`, related to the post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585501/usage-of-caret-with-gbm-method-for-multiclass-classification)? Thanks though for your suggestion.

Comment: I think so. Try updating caret and gbm.